# Do unused PEI sheets degrade over time?

Tags: build-plate, build-surface, pei

Will build surfaces coated in PEI lose their qualities, such as adhesiveness, if left unused but removed from packaging for long periods of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PEI will be fine. It's widely used in industrial high impact, high heat and high repetitiveness parts because it doesn't degrade easily. Probably some in your car.